# How FILD and FSTP work?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86, stack, fpu

I've searched over the net, and everywhere it says: FILD converts the two's complement of an
integer to 80 bit extended precision float, and puts it on top of the floats stack.
So, I've had a program do that, but the result I get is unexpected.

Example:
I have the number 0xFF20A810 in memory (let's say in 0x40000000)
fild [0x40000000]
fstp [0x40010000]

The result I get is 0x41EFE41502000000. How is the number converted?
I'm in the middle of a crackme which uses this, and I just can't find a solution.

Thank you

Comment: What were you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 3):

0x41EFE41502000000 is 4280330256.0 in double precision. 0xFF20A810 is 4280330256 as an unsigned integer.

So you accidentally loaded it, I think, as qword, and got lucky (the other bytes were zero).